# Are FIN packets guaranteed to arrive?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, winsock

In the 4-way handshake, we have the following:

```
FIN ------->
<------- ACK
<---x--- FIN (what if this packet is lost?)
ACK ------->
```

What happens if the third packet is lost, will it be re-transmitted? Note that by the time the third packet is sent, the program will have probably destroyed the socket, and so it can't send anything anymore!

Comment: Never trust network, everything is possible. Nothing is guaranteed

Comment: It will wait for a response until a timout kicks in.

Answer (score 3):

### TCP protocol

> All segments preceding and including FIN will be retransmitted until acknowledged.

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793

### Socket

You can use your operating system tools to see open TCP sockets and their states. During the TCP finalization the socket is first open for bi-directional communication, then each side closes its direction and each FIN has to be acknowledged before the resources are freed in the operating system.

In order to retransmit the FIN packet, the connection must be still represented in the OS until the FIN is acked or timed out.

Comment: So when the third packet is sent (FIN packet), and when I call `closesocket()` to destroy the socket, the socket is not really destroyed, right? but rather it waits for an ACK packet from the other side, and if the ACK packet has not been received after a certain time, it re-transmits the FIN packet?

Comment: Also I have another question, what will happen if after the FIN packet has been sent, the other computer on the other side has been unplugged from power, this means that the sender will never receive a FIN packet (because there is no one to send it). So what will happen in this case, will the sender wait for ever until a FIN packet is received (which will never arrive)?

Comment: That's covered by a timeout that is usually determined by operating system configuration. It's certainly not going to wait forever.

Comment: @user4572253: the operating system has to keep track of the connection, even after you've closed the socket, until the handshake is complete and the wait period (in case there are packets still in transit) has expired.  Whether it does that by keeping the socket object alive, or just tracks the connection separately, is an implementation detail subject to change.  In Windows, IIRC, you will be able to see the connection via `netstat`, and if your process exits, ownership of the connection is reassigned to the system process.  (Or something like that, my recollection is fuzzy.)